# dateFromString works different in iOS 4.3.4 ?

Tags: nsdateformatter, ios4

Is there any changes regarding NSDateFormatter in iOS 4.3.4? Because i  upgraded my iTouch os to 4.3.4 yesterday and found that some of my code related to NSDateFormatter is stop to work.

```
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];

NSDate *date_ = [outputFormatter dateFromString:@"08:00 AM"];
NSLog(@"Date:%@",date_);

[outputFormatter release];
```

**OUTPUT**

> iOS 4.3.1 : 1970-01-01 02:30:00 +0000
>
> iOS 4.3.4 : null.

Any ideas????

Comment: what i have to finally achieve is the sorted list of times.. Suppose i have array with different time in AM/PM format (like 08:00 AM,04:15 PM , 08:30AM). I want to sort them and this will only be possible if we can convert them to NSDate and apply compare.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code does **NOT** work in iOS 4.3.1... If you look at the date, you should notice that it is January 1970, or the common "year zero" in computer programming.

I think you should have put "HH:mm" instead of "h:mm a". The doubled h doesn't mean two digits, it is just some convention made up by ISO. And regarding the "AM-PM" parameter, I think it comes from locale.

Look at the documentation of **NSDate** for **setLocale**. Your parameter should be **@"en-US"** I think.

I hope it helped you.

Regards.